# How can I change the design of the Search Core Result WebPart from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, search, web-parts

I have a very simple question for good sharepoint developers I think, but at the moment im too blind to see the solution. I'm very pleased about any hint.

What I need to do is to change the design of the Search Core Result WebPart, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the WebPart and change the XSL for your own.

[image]

Try IT ;)